# Can't Boot An Intel Equipped Laptop From the Burned ISO For 13.10 ISP (X386)

Tags: cpu, pae

Keep getting an error message that "This kernel requires the following features not present on this CPU: pae".  I'm running an Intel Pentium M 2.0 GHz, with 2 GB of RAM on a 60 GB hard drive.  This is a Dell Latitude D600.  I burned the Ubuntu-13.10-desktop ISO on a DVD with the native Windows 7 Disc Image Burner.  Any info on this issue?  Assumed it would run as I've more that met the system requirements with this machine.

Comment: Your hardware is not up to the latest version of ubuntu but you may be OK with Lubuntu or Xubuntu 12.04 [see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE)

Answer (score 0):

please have a look here, report your problem and subscribe to the bug report:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/baltix/+bug/930447